# Understanding render error in React

Tags: html, reactjs

This is my first experience with react.
I don't understand why the following code returns an error on the `render` function.

```
    var LikeButton = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { liked: false };
        }

        render: function() {
            if (this.state.liked)
                return <div>Ti piace!</div>
            else
                return <a href="#" onClick={this.doLike}>Mi piace</a>
        }

        doLike: function() {
            this.setState({ liked: true });
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, document.body);
```

This code is in tag `<script type = "text/babel">`.

Comment: wat is the error ?? !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`React.createClass`takes an object as a parameter, and every property of an object needs to be separated by a comma (**,**).

You just need to do this:

```
var LikeButton = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { liked: false };
    }, // comma

    render: function() {
        if (this.state.liked)
            return <div>Ti piace!</div>
        else
            return <a href="#" onClick={this.doLike}>Mi piace</a>
    }, // comma

    doLike: function() {
        this.setState({ liked: true });
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<LikeButton />, document.body);
```

You can see your code working on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/qpm8jp0a/).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that while you provided `babel` in script type, it doesn't mean that your code actually compiled.

You can try [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) utility to setup valid environment for React development.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token (7:3)
   5 |          }
   6 |  
>  7 |          render: function() {
     |    ^
   8 |              if (this.state.liked)
   9 |                  return <div>Ti piace!</div>
  10 |              else
    at Parser.pp.raise (browser.js:65620)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (browser.js:66850)
    at Parser.pp.expect (browser.js:66844)
    at Parser.pp.parseObj (browser.js:65244)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (browser.js:65040)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (browser.js:68226)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (browser.js:64884)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (browser.js:64865)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (browser.js:64811)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (browser.js:64793)
```